# Can a tag be removed?

Tags: support, tags

I believe I made the tag [sims3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sims3) by accident at one point. when I made another question about it today, I noticed there were 2 tags: [sims3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sims3) and [sims-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sims-3). I retagged all my older questions under the [sims3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sims3) tag to [sims-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sims-3) but now there is still [sims3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sims3) with 0 questions.

Can this be removed or will it be removed after a certain time of no questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a tag has 0 instances at the end of the day, it is removed from the system. So retagging it away is the way to go for this.

Answer (score 3):

A tag with no questions (or just 1 question) will be removed after a while. You can also ask a moderator (via the "flag for moderator attention" or [ask in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge)) to merge the tags.

Comment: A 0-count tag is eliminated at the end of the day. A 1-count tag is eliminated after 6 months. If there's only one instance and the tag should be removed, one should simply untag the question.

Comment: @Grace you're ruining my scheme of generating more work for the mod team :(

Comment: Curious: as soon as you divest yourself from moderation, you want to make more work for the moderators? :P

Comment: @Raven naturally! :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the effect of caching; the tag will disappear from the list when it's refreshed.